# idea remote tomcat

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, tomcat

Как в *Intellij Idea* настроить деплой на *Tomcat server remote*?

К примеру у меня в сети есть:  сервер на *Ubuntu 14.04*, в которой крутится *XAMPP5.6.12(apache+mysql)* и *tomcat7*, а также рабочий ноутбук с *win10+ideaU14+XAMPP5.6.12*.

Пока делаю *java-web* проект, пользуюсь локальным *tomcat*, а для 'боевой' работы необходимо заливать на линуксовый сервер и без привязки к ноутбуку.

Comment: Что значит для `боевой` ? Вы планируете в продайкшен из IDEA заливать код?

Comment: да именно так в продакшен, сейчас заливаю вручную war'ник, но хочется автоматом из idea

Comment: По мне это не самая лучшая идеи. Есть решения для выкатывания решения в продакшен из репозиториев, называет это Continuous integration. У того же JetBrains есть TeamCity. Но даже это по моему требует очень тщательной работы с тестами, чтобы они покрывали все возможные случаи.

Comment: у моей программы не самая высокая ответственность, к тому-же есть доступ залить вручную в любой момент. просто я не нашел пока инструкции по настройке в idea - tomcat server /remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ответ из комментария [@Vartlok](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177499/vartlok):

---

По мне — это не самая лучшая идея. Есть решения для выкатывания решения в продакшен из репозиториев, называется это *Continuous integration*. У того же *JetBrains* есть *TeamCity*. Но даже это, по-моему, требует очень тщательной работы с тестами, чтобы они покрывали все возможные случаи.